# Upper bound for $\sum\limits_{i=2}^{N}{{{x}_{i}}({{x}_{i-1}}+{{x}_{i}})}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, inequality

Let $x_1, ..., x_N$ be $N$ arbitrary positive integers, and their sum is a constant number $C$, that is, $x_1+x_2+...+x_N=C$. Is it possible to find an upper bound for the following sum in term of $C$ (the tighter the better):

$\sum\limits_{i=2}^{N}{{{x}_{i}}({{x}_{i-1}}+{{x}_{i}})}$

Comment: You can pretty easily get $2C^2$; and, for $C\gg N$ (is $N$ supposed to go to $\infty$, or is it also a constant? It has to be, as by assumption $C\geq N$) you can easily achieve $C^2/2$, say.

Comment: Yes, $N \ll C$, $N$ is a very small constant, and $C$ is a large constant.

Comment: Then, you can achieve $\leq 2C^2$ immediately as a genral upper bound, and very easily $\geq 0.99C^2$ for some setting of the $x_i$'s.

Answer (score 1):

*Gathering comments I had made under the OP's question.*

Clearly, we have $\max_{1\leq i\leq N} x_i \leq C$, and therefore
$$
\sum_{i=2}^N x_i \underbrace{(x_{i-1}+x_i)}_{\leq 2\max_{1\leq j\leq N} x_j} \leq 2C\sum_{i=2}^N x_i\leq 2C\sum_{i=1}^N x_i = 2C^2 \tag{1}
$$

Further, consider the case where $x_1=\cdots=x_{N-1}=1$ and $x_N=C-(N-1)$. Then, assuming $N\ll C$ (e.g., $N < \frac{C}{10}$) as motivated by the comments below the question, we have $x_N^2 \geq \frac{81}{100}C^2$, from which
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N x_i (x_{i-1}+x_i)\geq x_N(x_N+x_{N-1}) \geq x_N^2 \geq  0.8C^2 \tag{2}
$$
showing than without further assumptions a bound with a quadratic dependence on $C$ as in $(1)$ is the best achievable.

---

As noted by [dezdichado](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/152744/dezdichado) in the comments, one can improve very easily the upper bound by a factor $2$ *(showing basically the optimal bound of $C^2$, since $(1-\epsilon)C^2$ is not possible, for any fixed $\epsilon >0$, by adapting the lower bound above)* by noting that
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=2}^N x_i (x_{i-1}+x_i) &\leq \sum_{i=2}^N x_i (x_1+x_2+\dots+x_N) \\&\leq \sum_{i=1}^N x_i (x_1+x_2+\dots+x_N) = (x_1+x_2+\dots+x_N)^2 \\&= C^2\tag{3}\end{align}$$

Comment: actually the upper bound is easily $C^2$ because the whole expression is very clearly less than $(x_1+x_2+...+x_N)^2=C^2$

Comment: I think, in Clement C's proof, for any $i$,  $x_{i-1}+x_i \le x_1+\cdots + x_N= C$. so the final result is $\le C^2$

Comment: @JohnSmith Edited to add this.

Comment: Many thanks, Clement.

Comment: It seems $C^2$ is too large, is it possible to have a bound in terms of both $C$ and $N$ ?

Comment: @JohnSmith I believe you need further assumptions on the $x_i$'s, then, or on the relation between $C$ and $N$. Look at the "lower bound": if most of the $xi$'s are small and one of them is big, then the sum will be close to $(C-N)^2\simeq C^2$.

Comment: I mean the upper bound should rely on $C$ and $N$, because if I try $x_1=x_2=...=x_N=C/N$, the sum is $2C^2/N^2$, but I am not sure whether this is the upper bound of the sum.

Comment: It is not... of course, in *some* cases the bound $C^2$ will not be tight (since the sum is not *always* equal to $C^2$, but in some others it will be arbitrarily close to $C^2$. Hence, without further assumptions of the $x_i$'s, the best general bound you can give is $C^2$ (again, assuming $C\gg N$).

Comment: Any *general* bound must apply to all possible choices of $(x_i)_i$, in particular the one from the lower bound in my answer.

Comment: I mean given $N$ and $C$, is the maximum of this sum expressible in terms of $C$ and $N$,

Comment: And I am saying *you won't get better than $C^2$* (up to low order terms), *since there exist choices of $(x_i)_i$ that get arbitrarily close to $C^2$, for any fixed $C,N$.* If you could get a better bound, then this bound would apply to these $(x_i)_i$'s, and that'd be a contradiction. @JohnSmith

Answer (score 0):

The expression looks equal to $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=2}^{N}(x_{i-1} + x_i)^2 - \frac{1}{2} x_1^2$$ and that is much easier to estimate.

Comment: What is your upper bound in terms of $C$? Could you give me some hints: how to estimate the upper bound for $\sum_{i=2}^{N}(x_{i-1} + x_i)^2 $? Thanks.

Comment: Next, you make a substitution $$y_i = x_i + x_{i+1}, i \in {1, ..., n - 1}$$, and then it's trivial.

Comment: I've tried, but don't know how to estimate $\sum_{i=2}^N y_i^2$...

Comment: Are you sure of your equality? Say, $x_N = C \gg 1$, and all others are $1$. Then the OP's sum is $\simeq C^2$, while yours is $\simeq C^2/2$.

Comment: @ClementC. Sure, forgot to add $$\frac{1}{2}x_N^2$$, thanks!

Comment: Well, slightly less trivial, y's sum up to a value somewhat lesser than C and x1 and xN interfere... Anyway, the sum of squares has been questioned several times on this site, and that any valid answer would give an appropriate estimate.